# How Device memory allocation happens

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage

Under the `Memory` settings entry, there are several categories such as `Apps` and `Documents`.

What is considered as part of the `Misc` category? It's taking up a huge amount of my device's memory.

Comment: Everything not mentioned explicitly in the other sections. What *exactly* it is I cannot tell, but that would e.g. include logs (especially "tombstones").